# Grammar outside the Chomsky Hierarchy

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

This grammar describes a language that may fall outside the Chomsky Hierarchy (CH):

\begin{array}{l}
S \to abAbba \\
A \to abA \mid bbaB \\
B \to aab \\
\lambda \to  Aab \mid aB \\
\end{array}

Going down the list, it's not context-free, it's not regular, etc.  Getting all the way to RE languages, the production starting with $\lambda$ seems outside any possible language within the CH.  Does this grammar not fall within the CH?

Comment: Maybe I'm being thick, but what's $\lambda$?

Comment: Ah, OK, seems that $\lambda$ is simply the zero-length word. So your last production allows the right-hand side to be inserted anywhere, right?

Comment: Yes the $\lambda$ would be the empty string, and so that's a production starting from nothing to something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last rule of your *grammar* does not satisfy the requirements of a [formal grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar) (every rule in formal grammar must have at least one non-terminal symbol on the left-hand side), so it clearly cannot belong to any hierarchy of formal grammars.

That being said, the *language* produced by your grammar (under the intuitive semantics) falls into the class of recursively enumerable languages. At a glance, it should be sufficient to add a non-terminal symbol $L$, along with rules $L\rightarrow \lambda\ | LL$ and add $L$ before, after and between each pair of characters on the right-hand sides of the rules (e.g. the third rule would become $L\rightarrow LaLaLbL$).

As **coffeemath** correctly observed, the resulting grammar will be context-free, so the language itself is context-free, instead of being *just* recursively enumerable.

Comment: With the extra symbol $L$ as suggested, does this now become context-free, since after the suggestion all rules have no context combinations to the left of the productions?

Comment: @coffeemath: Certainly looks like it to me.